# NPM Install blocked - Import Dependencies through Local file system

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, package, dependencies

Hi We are using jenkins and have a step in pipeline where we download dependencies such as mocha, cucumber etc. using

```
npm install
```

The client jenkins is not having internet access nor they have any dependency management server such as artefactory.

Is it possible to bundle the required dependencies from node_modules in zip or tar form and the same can be imported by them in global scope. So there is no need to run npm install for each job and they are available as global packages.

Is it that each project such as cucumber etc. needs to be downloaded separately and imported as file path.

Please share your thoughts as I am not able to find much information  on what  appeared to be a common problem initially with Organizations generally not allowing outbound internet on their servers.

thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [npm-pack-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-pack-all) that packs all of the `node_modules` as part of the artifact.